# event handler are not working in asynchronous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

i am filling up my dropdowns using this ajax call ..selectItems create select option tags in html using attribute_map

```
var $el = this.$el(model);
        var rule_title = "Job Family: ";
        var attribute_map = [];
        var current_object = this;
        $el.append(this.getRuleTitle(rule_title, model));
        jQuery.ajax({
        url : "<%= Rails.configuration.url_prefix           %>/team/index/get_rule_attribute_values",
        type : "GET",
        data : { name : "jobFamily" },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            var attribute_array = data.value.rule_attribute_values;
            attribute_array.sort(function(a,b){
                if(a.display_name > b.display_name){
                    return 1;
                }
                if(a.display_name < b.display_name){
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            var index = 0;
            var obj;
            for (obj in attribute_array){
                attribute_map[index] = [];
                attribute_map[index][0] = attribute_array[index].display_name + " ( " + attribute_array[index].internal_name + " ) " ;
                attribute_map[index][1] = attribute_array[index].internal_name;
                index++;
            }
            current_object.selectItems($el,
                          attribute_map,
                          "jobFamily", model.jobFamily, {multiple : "multiple", "data-placeholder" : "Add Constraint..."}, "400px");
        },
        complete : function() {
            console.log("completed");
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){
            var requestResponse = {
            httpStatus: jqXHR.status,
             error:jqXHR.statusText,
         };
         }
         });
```

when i put async as false ..event handler works fine but in synchronous call , the just doesn't do anything 
event handler looks like

```
$('.chosen-select jobFamily').on('change',function(evt, params){
                console.log("completeddddddd");
                var value = $('.chosen-select jobFamily').val();
                console.log(value);
                if (value == null) {
                    // Input is empty, so uncheck the box.
                    $('.jobFamily').prop("checked", false);
                } else {
                    // Make sure the box is checked.
                    $('.jobFamily').prop("checked", true);
                }
            });
        });
```

where '.chosen-select jobFamily' is class of select tag and '.jobFamily' is class of  check box ... i have tried writing my jquery inside complete argument of ajax call , i tried writing my jquery inside

```
$('document).bind('ajaxComplete',function({
//above jquery
});
```

please help . i have spent more than 2 days on that . all code lies inside ready function.

Comment: Can you post the code including the $(document).ready?
I mean, this is probably caused by something related to timing, so seeing where the ready is called is crucial.
Also, did you try to use console.log($('.chosen-select jobFamily').length) before calling the $('.chosen-select jobFamily').on..., in order to see that an element was actually found?

Comment: you missed `.` in `$('.chosen-select jobFamily')` . change this to `$('.chosen-select .jobFamily')`

Comment: i can't post the whole code because it is 900 lines of code

Comment: $('.chosen-select jobFamily') is the class of select tag

Comment: @ShaharB length is zero . i don't know why . i am taking this 'chosen-select jobFamily' class after inspecting element in browser

Comment: Obviously length would be zero. As I already told you are missing `.`  `$('.chosen-select jobFamily')` change this to `$('.chosen-select .jobFamily')`

Comment: @vinayakj you were right dude !! Thanks a lot .. u really made my day.
can you suggest me some good link to study jquery,javascript concepts from scratch